# Table doesn't fit page even with rotating

Tags: tables, rotating

[image]

I have two tables (only one is shown in above picture) that are too wide and even with rotating the tables with the sidewaystable package they don't fit to one page. It is a must for me to fit both on two separate pages. Unfortunately I cannot shortstack the numbers (obviously) and already use the smallest font (tiny). How can I go about solving this problem? Could I somehow use the free space at the bottom of the page? Maybe a solution without rotating the table? Thank you so much for your advice!

```
documentclass[12pt]{report}
        \usepackage{multirow}
        \usepackage{bigstrut}
    \usepackage{booktabs}
    \usepackage{rotating}


        \begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
  \centering
  \caption{Total members per cantonal gymnastics organization 1888 - 1930}
  \tiny
    \begin{tabular}{lrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr}
     \hline
          & 88    & 90    & 91    & 92    & 94    & 97    & 98    & 99    & 00  & 01    & 02    & 03    & 04    & 05    & 06    & 07    & 08    & 27    & 28    & 30 \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    AG    & 1'393 & 1'514 & 1'566 & 1'569 & 1'627 & 2'011 & 1'963 & 2'080 & 2'408 & 2'526 & 2'520 & 2'635 & 2'907 & 3'087 & 3'450 & 3'845 & 4'081 & 11'503 & 11'704 & 12'043 \bigstrut[t]\\
    AP    & 474   & 458   & 517   & 611   & 581   & 740   & 781   & 876   & 908   & 1'035 & 1'073 & 1'065 & 1'134 & 1'160 & 1'323 & 1'452 & 1'573 & 2'262 & 2'420 & 2'316 \\
    BL    & 587   & 648   & 674   & 868   & 1'020 & 1'258 & 1'379 & 1'498 & 1'423 & 1'466 & 1'562 & 1'688 & 1'821 & 1'781 & 1'824 & 2'031 & 2'106 & 4'964 & 5'104 & 5'284 \\
    BS    & 629   & 872   & 1'246 & 1'269 & 1'406 & 1'778 & 1'928 & 2'344 & 2'399 & 2'353 & 2'388 & 2'557 & 2'598 & 2'667 & 2'526 & 2'761 & 3'015 & 4'680 & 4'750 & 4'666 \\
    BE    & 2'412 & 2'474 & 2'458 & 2'543 & 2'778 & 2'878 & 3'213 & 3'264 & 4'366 & 4'429 & 6'511 & 6'516 & 5'559 & 6'128 & 6'722 & 7'767 & 8'678 & 18'277 & 18'440 & 18'296 \\
    C     & 707   & 731   & 754   & 2'057 & 1'045 & 1'260 & 1'327 & 1'298 & 1'350 & 1'265 & 1'253 & 1'293 & 1'426 & 1'445 & 1'523 & 1'896 & 2'086 & 1'964 & 2'167 & 2'440 \\
    FR    & 282   & 331   & 397   & 853   & 461   & 480   & 573   & 726   & 824   & 743   & 743   & 755   & 633   & 637   & 655   & 752   & 716   & 1'399 & 1'390 & 1'443 \\
    GE    &       &       &       & 373   & 946   & 928   & 988   & 1'084 & 1'143 & 1'107 & 1'129 & 1'056 & 1'653 & 1'862 & 2'060 & 2'143 & 2'160 & 3'312 & 3'265 & 3'027 \\
    GL    & 321   & 372   & 422   & 817   & 377   & 480   & 502   & 562   & 594   & 629   & 581   & 648   & 690   & 731   & 690   & 753   & 721   & 1'758 & 1'837 & 1'932 \\
    GR    & 411   & 552   & 546   & 467   & 563   & 657   & 660   & 698   & 734   & 883   & 954   & 1'056 & 1'171 & 1'441 & 1'460 & 1'460 & 1'556 & 1'614 & 1'717 & 1'793 \\
    LU    &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & 4'228 & 4'280 & 4'693 \\
    NE    &       &       &       & 566   & 1'674 & 1'732 & 1'782 & 1'988 & 1'987 & 2'006 & 2'241 & 2'328 & 2'267 & 2'347 & 2'389 & 2'658 & 2'697 & 3'155 & 3'097 & 3'222 \\
    SH    & 334   & 264   & 425   & 1'752 & 566   & 645   & 698   & 735   & 723   & 744   & 937   & 1'051 & 1'113 & 1'192 & 1'203 & 1'313 & 1'427 & 2'605 & 2'623 & 2'868 \\
    SO    & 551   & 791   & 862   & 493   & 780   & 871   & 1'098 & 1'084 & 998   & 1'146 & 1'061 & 1'154 & 1'299 & 1'505 & 1'666 & 1'714 & 1'739 & 5'661 & 5'761 & 6'392 \\
    SG    & 1'422 & 1'865 & 1'863 & 955   & 2'179 & 2'372 & 2'340 & 2'558 & 2'740 & 2'892 & 2'949 & 3'177 & 3'441 & 3'631 & 4'048 & 4'448 & 5'083 & 9'175 & 9'167 & 8'846 \\
    TI    &       & 392   & 392   & 795   & 402   & 414   & 381   & 386   & 386   & 384   & 619   & 486   & 519   & 402   & 452   & 454   & 450   & 1'034 & 1'025 & 899 \\
    TG    & 743   & 829   & 879   & 402   & 1'121 & 1'249 & 1'360 & 1'382 & 1'486 & 1'669 & 1'745 & 1'882 & 2'019 & 2'159 & 2'284 & 2'454 & 2'776 & 6'117 & 6'057 & 6'030 \\
    VD    &       &       &       & 2'088 & 2'394 & 2'627 & 3'132 & 3'114 & 3'028 & 2'886 & 3'172 & 3'040 & 3'343 & 3'254 & 2'937 & 3'061 & 2'992 & 7'073 & 6'533 & 5'821 \\
    VS    &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & 230   & 235   & 268   & 330   & 298   & 341   & 341   & 341   & 341   & 974   & 1'003 & 949 \\
    ZH    & 4'144 & 5'000 & 5'488 & 5'752 & 5'576 & 7'445 & 7'858 & 8'410 & 8'807 & 9'125 & 9'465 & 10'202 & 10'491 & 11'139 & 11'546 & 13'262 & 14'358 & 28'706 & 29'350 & 30'742 \bigstrut[b]\\
    \hline
    Total & 14'410 & 17'093 & 18'489 & 24'230 & 25'496 & 29'825 & 31'963 & 34'087 & 36'534 & 37'523 & 41'171 & 42'919 & 44'382 & 46'909 & 49'099 & 54'565 & 58'555 & 120'461 & 121'690 & 123'702 \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{sidewaystable}



\begin{sidewaystable}
  \centering
  \caption{Paying members per cantonal gymnastics organization 1888 - 1930}
  \tiny
    \begin{tabular}{lrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr}
    \hline
          & 88  & 90  & 91  & 92  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{94} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{97} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{98} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{99} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{00} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{01} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{02} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{03} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{04} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{05} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{06} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{07} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{08} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{27} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{28} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{30} \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    AG    & 909   & 1'029 & 1'166 & 1'201 & 1'313 & 1'604 & 1'560 & 1'632 & 1'910 & 1'962 & 1'978 & 2'023 & 2'253 & 2'424 & 2'720 & 3'175 & 3'330 & 10'099 & 10'247 & 10'881 \bigstrut[t]\\
    AP    & 132   & 458   & 443   & 515   & 487   & 610   & 648   & 747   & 785   & 908   & 948   & 941   & 1'006 & 1'031 & 1'187 & 1'321 & 1'418 & 2'084 & 2'225 & 2'118 \\
    BL    & 464   & 553   & 580   & 722   & 905   & 1'118 & 1'221 & 1'327 & 1'239 & 1'296 & 1'358 & 1'478 & 1'545 & 1'528 & 1'550 & 1'665 & 1'776 & 3'984 & 4'652 & 4'815 \\
    BS    & 428   & 640   & 919   & 900   & 1'210 & 1'598 & 1'690 & 2'052 & 2'169 & 2'097 & 2'120 & 2'242 & 2'278 & 2'307 & 2'191 & 2'350 & 2'567 & 4'016 & 4'192 & 4'367 \\
    BE    & 1'201 & 1'202 & 1'206 & 1'285 & 2'288 & 2'370 & 2'705 & 2'741 & 3'131 & 3'238 & 3'629 & 4'291 & 4'202 & 5'152 & 5'500 & 5'982 & 6'296 & 15'321 & 15'687 & 16'871 \\
    C     & 314   & 543   & 558   & 917   & 865   & 1'052 & 1'072 & 1'057 & 1'098 & 1'030 & 1'001 & 1'048 & 1'146 & 1'215 & 1'280 & 1'607 & 1'713 & 1'682 & 1'870 & 2'230 \\
    FR    & 237   & 282   & 312   & 678   & 379   & 385   & 460   & 613   & 702   & 646   & 631   & 641   & 585   & 580   & 599   & 651   & 657   & 1'245 & 1'242 & 1'263 \\
    GE    &       &       &       & 315   & 673   & 793   & 853   & 931   & 990   & 942   & 917   & 848   & 1'256 & 1'458 & 1'596 & 1'714 & 1'727 & 2'839 & 2'748 & 2'677 \\
    GL    & 112   & 352   & 327   & 473   & 307   & 377   & 384   & 403   & 453   & 445   & 430   & 461   & 504   & 529   & 506   & 474   & 518   & 1'606 & 1'659 & 1'756 \\
    GR    & 330   & 453   & 394   & 334   & 509   & 520   & 538   & 545   & 584   & 727   & 824   & 939   & 1'003 & 1'230 & 1'253 & 1'253 & 1'335 & 1'406 & 1'507 & 1'672 \\
    LU    &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & 3'628 & 3'740 & 4'378 \\
    NE    &       &       &       & 456   & 1'167 & 1'161 & 1'168 & 1'326 & 1'306 & 1'336 & 1'511 & 1'564 & 1'503 & 1'535 & 1'569 & 1'737 & 1'719 & 1'887 & 1'904 & 2'015 \\
    SH    & 216   & 206   & 216   & 661   & 450   & 483   & 568   & 632   & 598   & 592   & 751   & 839   & 912   & 1'003 & 1'004 & 1'135 & 1'245 & 2'302 & 2'330 & 2'678 \\
    SO    & 181   & 332   & 354   & 238   & 650   & 665   & 864   & 829   & 763   & 842   & 802   & 867   & 1'007 & 1'151 & 1'248 & 1'329 & 1'279 & 4'939 & 4'979 & 5'737 \\
    SG    & 1'214 & 1'523 & 1'574 & 310   & 1'816 & 2'034 & 1'977 & 2'139 & 2'297 & 2'453 & 2'489 & 2'626 & 2'907 & 3'092 & 3'430 & 3'833 & 4'309 & 7'781 & 7'962 & 8'168 \\
    TI    &       & 261   & 261   & 341   & 261   & 235   & 202   & 207   & 207   & 205   & 350   & 316   & 389   & 322   & 372   & 375   & 375   & 698   & 850   & 791 \\
    TG    & 288   & 285   & 285   & 261   & 879   & 1'052 & 1'156 & 1'152 & 1'251 & 1'443 & 1'484 & 1'574 & 1'709 & 1'834 & 1'955 & 2'112 & 2'405 & 5'359 & 5'362 & 5'451 \\
    VD    &       &       &       & 1'736 & 1'945 & 2'103 & 2'170 & 2'099 & 1'941 & 2'014 & 2'127 & 2'437 & 2'459 & 2'430 & 2'291 & 2'254 & 2'209 & 4'516 & 4'022 & 4'288 \\
    VS    &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & 188   & 191   & 209   & 276   & 244   & 295   & 295   & 295   & 295   & 906   & 901   & 870 \\
    ZH    & 1'717 & 1'403 & 1'607 & 1'600 & 4'520 & 5'947 & 6'192 & 6'825 & 7'200 & 7'329 & 7'738 & 8'303 & 8'482 & 9'162 & 9'676 & 10'840 & 11'706 & 24'769 & 25'507 & 28'290 \bigstrut[b]\\
    \hline
    Total & 7'743 & 9'522 & 10'202 & 12'943 & 20'624 & 24'107 & 25'428 & 27'257 & 28'812 & 29'696 & 31'297 & 33'714 & 35'390 & 38'278 & 40'222 & 44'102 & 46'879 & 101'067 & 103'586 & 111'316 \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{sidewaystable}


\end{document}
```

Comment: The suggestion would be to not put all the content in a single table...

Comment: It can be done but why do it this way, it is very hard on your readers (especially if printing to paper rather than a zoomabble format) why not at the very least have twice as many rows and half as many columns, so the data fits the page aspect ratio?

Comment: yes, I have used \tabcolsep for most of the tables so that I don't have to rotate them. However, there was one that I left rotated. It's only in the appendix so I guess it's OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that both tables have 21 [!] columns, the first order of business is to reduce the amount of intercolumn whitespace. The second order of business is to jettison all material that's not absolutely needed, such as the apostrophes that act as thousands-separators. If you set `\tabcolsep` -- the parameter that governs the amount of intercolumn whitespace -- to `2.5pt` (default value: `6pt`), it turns out to be unnecessary to choose a `\tiny` font size; `\scriptsize` works fine.

(no screenshot shown)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{bigstrut}
\usepackage{booktabs,rotating,caption}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}  % handy shortcut macro

\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}
\setlength\tabcolsep{2.5pt}  % default value: 6pt
  \centering
  \caption{Total members per cantonal gymnastics organization 1888--1930}
  \scriptsize
    \begin{tabular}{@{} l *{20}{r} @{}}
     \hline
          & 88    & 90    & 91    & 92    & 94    & 97    & 98    & 99    & 00  & 01    & 02    & 03    & 04    & 05    & 06    & 07    & 08    & 27    & 28    & 30 \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    AG    & 1393 & 1514 & 1566 & 1569 & 1627 & 2011 & 1963 & 2080 & 2408 & 2526 & 2520 & 2635 & 2907 & 3087 & 3450 & 3845 & 4081 & 11503 & 11704 & 12043 \bigstrut[t]\\
    AP    & 474   & 458   & 517   & 611   & 581   & 740   & 781   & 876   & 908   & 1035 & 1073 & 1065 & 1134 & 1160 & 1323 & 1452 & 1573 & 2262 & 2420 & 2316 \\
    BL    & 587   & 648   & 674   & 868   & 1020 & 1258 & 1379 & 1498 & 1423 & 1466 & 1562 & 1688 & 1821 & 1781 & 1824 & 2031 & 2106 & 4964 & 5104 & 5284 \\
    BS    & 629   & 872   & 1246 & 1269 & 1406 & 1778 & 1928 & 2344 & 2399 & 2353 & 2388 & 2557 & 2598 & 2667 & 2526 & 2761 & 3015 & 4680 & 4750 & 4666 \\
    BE    & 2412 & 2474 & 2458 & 2543 & 2778 & 2878 & 3213 & 3264 & 4366 & 4429 & 6511 & 6516 & 5559 & 6128 & 6722 & 7767 & 8678 & 18277 & 18440 & 18296 \\
    C     & 707   & 731   & 754   & 2057 & 1045 & 1260 & 1327 & 1298 & 1350 & 1265 & 1253 & 1293 & 1426 & 1445 & 1523 & 1896 & 2086 & 1964 & 2167 & 2440 \\
    FR    & 282   & 331   & 397   & 853   & 461   & 480   & 573   & 726   & 824   & 743   & 743   & 755   & 633   & 637   & 655   & 752   & 716   & 1399 & 1390 & 1443 \\
    GE    &       &       &       & 373   & 946   & 928   & 988   & 1084 & 1143 & 1107 & 1129 & 1056 & 1653 & 1862 & 2060 & 2143 & 2160 & 3312 & 3265 & 3027 \\
    GL    & 321   & 372   & 422   & 817   & 377   & 480   & 502   & 562   & 594   & 629   & 581   & 648   & 690   & 731   & 690   & 753   & 721   & 1758 & 1837 & 1932 \\
    GR    & 411   & 552   & 546   & 467   & 563   & 657   & 660   & 698   & 734   & 883   & 954   & 1056 & 1171 & 1441 & 1460 & 1460 & 1556 & 1614 & 1717 & 1793 \\
    LU    &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & 4228 & 4280 & 4693 \\
    NE    &       &       &       & 566   & 1674 & 1732 & 1782 & 1988 & 1987 & 2006 & 2241 & 2328 & 2267 & 2347 & 2389 & 2658 & 2697 & 3155 & 3097 & 3222 \\
    SH    & 334   & 264   & 425   & 1752 & 566   & 645   & 698   & 735   & 723   & 744   & 937   & 1051 & 1113 & 1192 & 1203 & 1313 & 1427 & 2605 & 2623 & 2868 \\
    SO    & 551   & 791   & 862   & 493   & 780   & 871   & 1098 & 1084 & 998   & 1146 & 1061 & 1154 & 1299 & 1505 & 1666 & 1714 & 1739 & 5661 & 5761 & 6392 \\
    SG    & 1422 & 1865 & 1863 & 955   & 2179 & 2372 & 2340 & 2558 & 2740 & 2892 & 2949 & 3177 & 3441 & 3631 & 4048 & 4448 & 5083 & 9175 & 9167 & 8846 \\
    TI    &       & 392   & 392   & 795   & 402   & 414   & 381   & 386   & 386   & 384   & 619   & 486   & 519   & 402   & 452   & 454   & 450   & 1034 & 1025 & 899 \\
    TG    & 743   & 829   & 879   & 402   & 1121 & 1249 & 1360 & 1382 & 1486 & 1669 & 1745 & 1882 & 2019 & 2159 & 2284 & 2454 & 2776 & 6117 & 6057 & 6030 \\
    VD    &       &       &       & 2088 & 2394 & 2627 & 3132 & 3114 & 3028 & 2886 & 3172 & 3040 & 3343 & 3254 & 2937 & 3061 & 2992 & 7073 & 6533 & 5821 \\
    VS    &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & 230   & 235   & 268   & 330   & 298   & 341   & 341   & 341   & 341   & 974   & 1003 & 949 \\
    ZH    & 4144 & 5000 & 5488 & 5752 & 5576 & 7445 & 7858 & 8410 & 8807 & 9125 & 9465 & 10202 & 10491 & 11139 & 11546 & 13262 & 14358 & 28706 & 29350 & 30742 \bigstrut[b]\\
    \hline
    Total & 14410 & 17093 & 18489 & 24230 & 25496 & 29825 & 31963 & 34087 & 36534 & 37523 & 41171 & 42919 & 44382 & 46909 & 49099 & 54565 & 58555 & 120461 & 121690 & 123702 \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{sidewaystable}



\begin{sidewaystable}
\setlength\tabcolsep{2.5pt}  % default value: 6pt
  \centering
  \caption{Paying members per cantonal gymnastics organization 1888--1930}  \label{tab:addlabel}
  \scriptsize
    \begin{tabular}{@{} l *{20}{r} @{}}
    \hline
          & 88  & 90  & 91  & 92  & \mc{94} & \mc{97} & \mc{98} & \mc{99} & \mc{00} & \mc{01} & \mc{02} & \mc{03} & \mc{04} & \mc{05} & \mc{06} & \mc{07} & \mc{08} & \mc{27} & \mc{28} & \mc{30} \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    AG    & 909   & 1029 & 1166 & 1201 & 1313 & 1604 & 1560 & 1632 & 1910 & 1962 & 1978 & 2023 & 2253 & 2424 & 2720 & 3175 & 3330 & 10099 & 10247 & 10881 \bigstrut[t]\\
    AP    & 132   & 458   & 443   & 515   & 487   & 610   & 648   & 747   & 785   & 908   & 948   & 941   & 1006 & 1031 & 1187 & 1321 & 1418 & 2084 & 2225 & 2118 \\
    BL    & 464   & 553   & 580   & 722   & 905   & 1118 & 1221 & 1327 & 1239 & 1296 & 1358 & 1478 & 1545 & 1528 & 1550 & 1665 & 1776 & 3984 & 4652 & 4815 \\
    BS    & 428   & 640   & 919   & 900   & 1210 & 1598 & 1690 & 2052 & 2169 & 2097 & 2120 & 2242 & 2278 & 2307 & 2191 & 2350 & 2567 & 4016 & 4192 & 4367 \\
    BE    & 1201 & 1202 & 1206 & 1285 & 2288 & 2370 & 2705 & 2741 & 3131 & 3238 & 3629 & 4291 & 4202 & 5152 & 5500 & 5982 & 6296 & 15321 & 15687 & 16871 \\
    C     & 314   & 543   & 558   & 917   & 865   & 1052 & 1072 & 1057 & 1098 & 1030 & 1001 & 1048 & 1146 & 1215 & 1280 & 1607 & 1713 & 1682 & 1870 & 2230 \\
    FR    & 237   & 282   & 312   & 678   & 379   & 385   & 460   & 613   & 702   & 646   & 631   & 641   & 585   & 580   & 599   & 651   & 657   & 1245 & 1242 & 1263 \\
    GE    &       &       &       & 315   & 673   & 793   & 853   & 931   & 990   & 942   & 917   & 848   & 1256 & 1458 & 1596 & 1714 & 1727 & 2839 & 2748 & 2677 \\
    GL    & 112   & 352   & 327   & 473   & 307   & 377   & 384   & 403   & 453   & 445   & 430   & 461   & 504   & 529   & 506   & 474   & 518   & 1606 & 1659 & 1756 \\
    GR    & 330   & 453   & 394   & 334   & 509   & 520   & 538   & 545   & 584   & 727   & 824   & 939   & 1003 & 1230 & 1253 & 1253 & 1335 & 1406 & 1507 & 1672 \\
    LU    &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & 3628 & 3740 & 4378 \\
    NE    &       &       &       & 456   & 1167 & 1161 & 1168 & 1326 & 1306 & 1336 & 1511 & 1564 & 1503 & 1535 & 1569 & 1737 & 1719 & 1887 & 1904 & 2015 \\
    SH    & 216   & 206   & 216   & 661   & 450   & 483   & 568   & 632   & 598   & 592   & 751   & 839   & 912   & 1003 & 1004 & 1135 & 1245 & 2302 & 2330 & 2678 \\
    SO    & 181   & 332   & 354   & 238   & 650   & 665   & 864   & 829   & 763   & 842   & 802   & 867   & 1007 & 1151 & 1248 & 1329 & 1279 & 4939 & 4979 & 5737 \\
    SG    & 1214 & 1523 & 1574 & 310   & 1816 & 2034 & 1977 & 2139 & 2297 & 2453 & 2489 & 2626 & 2907 & 3092 & 3430 & 3833 & 4309 & 7781 & 7962 & 8168 \\
    TI    &       & 261   & 261   & 341   & 261   & 235   & 202   & 207   & 207   & 205   & 350   & 316   & 389   & 322   & 372   & 375   & 375   & 698   & 850   & 791 \\
    TG    & 288   & 285   & 285   & 261   & 879   & 1052 & 1156 & 1152 & 1251 & 1443 & 1484 & 1574 & 1709 & 1834 & 1955 & 2112 & 2405 & 5359 & 5362 & 5451 \\
    VD    &       &       &       & 1736 & 1945 & 2103 & 2170 & 2099 & 1941 & 2014 & 2127 & 2437 & 2459 & 2430 & 2291 & 2254 & 2209 & 4516 & 4022 & 4288 \\
    VS    &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & 188   & 191   & 209   & 276   & 244   & 295   & 295   & 295   & 295   & 906   & 901   & 870 \\
    ZH    & 1717 & 1403 & 1607 & 1600 & 4520 & 5947 & 6192 & 6825 & 7200 & 7329 & 7738 & 8303 & 8482 & 9162 & 9676 & 10840 & 11706 & 24769 & 25507 & 28290 \bigstrut[b]\\
    \hline
    Total & 7743 & 9522 & 10202 & 12943 & 20624 & 24107 & 25428 & 27257 & 28812 & 29696 & 31297 & 33714 & 35390 & 38278 & 40222 & 44102 & 46879 & 101067 & 103586 & 111316 \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}%
 %
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Fantastic! Couldn't resist to this comment ;)